# Python(matrices), rana saltando en mosaicos

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para aprender a manipular matrices en Python; el enunciado es el siguiente:

> Una rana se desplaza sobre una habitación rectangular cuyo piso está
> formado por MxN mosaicos. La rana salta de un mosaico a otro, en forma
> aleatoria, pero nunca en diagonal, y su misión es recorrer todos los
> mosaicos del salón, pisando cada uno de ellos al menos una vez.

- Queremos saber cuántos saltos le toma a la rana pisar todos los mosaicos. Considere que la rana no va a poder saltar más allá de los límites de la habitación, y que parte de la posición 0,0.
- Sugerencia: Declare y cree una matriz de enteros de tamaño MxN, e inicialícela con ceros. Cada vez que la rana pise el mosaico en la posición (i, j) por primera vez, actualice el valor correspondiente en la matriz (por ejemplo a 1), para indicar que ese mosaico ya ha sido pisado. Esto sólo debe hacerse si en la posición correspondiente había anteriormente un cero, es decir, si el mosaico no había sido pisado previamente.
- Sugerencia: Para decidir hacia donde salta la rana genere un número aleatorio, de un conjunto de 4 valores posibles, de forma tal que cada uno de los valores represente una dirección de salto.

La función que cree no me llena la matriz con 1, existen ocasiones que quedan 0 en la matriz y si cambio algo queda en un bucle infinito, rellenando con 1, si alguien puede darme un consejo de como saber cuando la matriz se encuentra llena de 1 para detener el bucle me ayudaria mucho:

```
def recorrido(M):
    cont = 0

    i = 0
    while i < len(M):
        j = 0
        while j < len(M[i]):
            if M[i][j] == 0:
                print(f"--salto {i},{j}")
                M[i][j] = 1
                salto = random.randint(1,4)
                
                if salto == 4 and i-1 >= 0:   #arriba
                    i -=1
                    cont +=1
                    print("arriba")
                
                elif salto == 2 and i+1 < len(M):  # abajo
                    i += 1
                    cont +=1
                    print("abajo")

                elif salto == 3 and j-1 >= 0:    #izquierda
                    j -= 1
                    cont +=1
                    print("izquierda")
                
                elif salto == 1 and j+1 < len(M[i]):  # derecha
                    j += 1
                    cont +=1
                    print("derecha")
            else:
                cont +=1
                j+=1
        i+=1
                
    for i in range(len(M)):
        print(M[i])
```

Comment: en diagonal te refieres a cualquier diagonal o puede saltar en diagonal pero con varios espacios de separación, por ejemplo si empieza en una esquina, puede saltar a la otra esquina opuesta?

Comment: es sin diagonales, solo arriba, abajo, derecha e izquierda de la posicion i y solo un espacio por salto.

Comment: quieres que el fin del tablero sea *infinito*  osea que si se va por un borde aparezca por el otro lado??

Comment: no, que si llega a un borde lo ideal seria que el numero random cambie hasta que se pueda mover hacia dentro del tablero

Comment: hice algo, y creo que se adapta a lo que quieres, ahora pongo la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Mi solución:

Para controlar las movidas defino una lista con los cuatro desplazamientos válidos en el eje (x, y)

```
movidas = [(1,0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]
```

Declaro una matriz, inicializandola con ceros

```
filas = 3
columnas = 5
matriz = [[0] * columnas for i in range(filas)]
```

La variable `celdas` me dice cuantas faltan por llenar, mientras que `saltos` me da el número de saltos válidos hasta el momento:

```
celdas = filas * columnas
saltos = 0
```

Ahora el proceso. `(fila, columna)` son las coordenadas de la rana. En cada iteración elijo una de las cuatro movidas posibles y calculo las nuevas coordenadas.

Si las coordenadas están fuera de limites, paso a la siguiente iteración, hasta conseguir las coordenadas de una celda válida.

Una vez obtenida una celda válida, reviso que esté desocupada, en cuyo caso rebajo `celdas` y actualizo la matriz.

```
delta_fila, delta_columna = movidas[randint(0,3)]
nueva_fila, nueva_columna = fila + delta_fila, columna + delta_columna
if 0 <= nueva_columna < columnas and 0 <= nueva_fila < filas:
    saltos += 1
    fila, columna = nueva_fila, nueva_columna
    if not matriz[fila][columna]:
        print(f"({fila}, {columna}) -> ", end="")
        matriz[fila][columna] = 1
        pprint(matriz)
        celdas -= 1

print(f"Resuelto en {saltos} saltos")
```

**Demo**

```
from random import randint
from pprint import pprint

movidas = [(1,0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]
filas = 3
columnas = 5
matriz = [[0] * columnas for i in range(filas)]
celdas = filas * columnas
saltos = 0

fila, columna = 0, 0
while celdas:
    delta_fila, delta_columna = movidas[randint(0,3)]
    nueva_fila, nueva_columna = fila + delta_fila, columna + delta_columna
    if 0 <= nueva_columna < columnas and 0 <= nueva_fila < filas:
        saltos += 1
        fila, columna = nueva_fila, nueva_columna
        if not matriz[fila][columna]:
            print(f"({fila}, {columna}) -> ", end="")
            matriz[fila][columna] = 1
            pprint(matriz)
            celdas -= 1

print(f"Resuelto en {saltos} saltos")
```

produce en cada línea las coordenadas de la rana y como queda la matriz luego de ejecutado la movida. Se descartan las movidas fuera de límites y aquellas que caen en una celda ocupada.

```
(0, 1) -> [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
(0, 0) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
(1, 1) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
(1, 0) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
(1, 2) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
(2, 2) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
(2, 1) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
(2, 3) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(1, 3) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(1, 4) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(0, 4) -> [[1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(0, 2) -> [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(2, 0) -> [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(2, 4) -> [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
(0, 3) -> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
Resuelto en 71 saltos
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno te traigo mi implementación de problema, no leí tu código pues me confunde mucho así que mejor hice mi implementación.

Dividí el programa en 4 funciones.

1. `gen_tablero(n,m)`: genera el tablero inicial de NxM.
2. `movimiento(pos,limits)`: devuelve el movimiento a realizar (arriba, abajo, derecha, izquierda).
3. `recorrido(tablero)`: mueve a la rana de posición hasta que haya visitado todo.
4. `main()`: se encarga de ejecutar todo.

**gen_tablero(n,m)**

Esta función recibe como parámetros las dimensiones del tablero y lo crea usando una comprensión de lista.

```py
import random #primero importamos el modulo

def gen_tablero(m,n):
    tablero = [[0 for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
    return tablero
```

**movimiento(pos,limits)**

recibe como parámetro la posición actual y los limites del tablero. El parámetro `pos` es una tupla `(fila,col)`. Primero se trata de mover a la rana en las posiciones tipicas.

- arriba: Tendremos que restarle 1 a la fila, manteniendo la columna
- abajo: Tendremos que sumarle 1 a la fila, manteniendo la columna
- derecha: Tendremos que sumarle 1 a la columna, manteniendo la fila
- izquierda: Tendremos que restarle 1 a la columna, manteniendo la fila

Pero aquí viene lo interesante, y que pasa si estamos en el limite del tablero? Pues por eso existe el parámetro `limit` el cual también es una tupla que indica el limite en el eje X (n) y Y (m), por tal razón tendremos que verificar no pasar de ele limite. Algo curioso es que podemos ir en reversa, como sabes podemos acceder a una lista de la forma `list[-1]` que indica la ultima posición, por lo que también podemos hacer `list[-4]`. Por tal razón no podemos hacer `if pos[n] > limit[n]` por que puede tener un valor negativo, la solución es convertir la posición a entero y eso se hace sacando su valor absoluto.

Para determinar el valor, ya sea de la columna o fila, usamos la sintaxis de operador ternario, donde en caso la posición supera el limite le pones el valor de 0

```py
def movimiento(pos,limits):
    #posiciones en forma de indice
    lim_inf = limits[0]-1
    lim = limits[1]-1

    #definimos movimientos
    arriba = (pos[0]-1 if abs(pos[0]) !=lim_inf else 0, pos[1])
    abajo = (pos[0]+1 if abs(pos[0]) !=lim_inf else 0, pos[1])
    
    derecha = (pos[0], pos[1]+1 if abs(pos[1]) !=lim else 0)
    izq = (pos[0],pos[1]-1 if abs(pos[1]) !=lim else 0)

    #lo ponemos en una lista
    movidas = [arriba,abajo,derecha,izq]
    mov = random.choice(movidas) #escogemos una aleatoria
    return mov
```

Ahora solo nos falta hacer el recorrido. Para esto tendremos que hacer un ciclo `while True` donde solo se detenga en caso hayamos visitado todos los mosaicos. Y como sabes cuando hemos visitado todos?. La forma en que se me ocurrió fue hallando la suma de todo el tablero, como los mosaicos visitados tienen el valor de 1 solo sumamos y verificamos si la suma es igual a la dimensión del tablero.

Luego solo nos faltaría usar las funciones anteriores, para crear el tablero y para hacer el movimiento.

```py
def recorrido(tablero):
    print("Start game")
    game = True
    pos = (0,0) #posicion actual
    saltos = 0
    tablero[0][0]=1 #marcamos como vistiado la posicion inicial
    limites = len(tablero),len(tablero[0]) #definimos los limites

    while game:
        pos = movimiento(pos,(limites[0],limites[1])) #siguiente movimiento a realizar
        fila,col = pos[0],pos[1] #obtenemos la fila y columna

        if tablero[fila][col] == 1: #comprobamos que no este visitado
            suma = sum( sum(row) for row in tablero ) #hayamos la suma
            if suma == limites[0]*limites[1]: game=False #verificamos si todavia nos falta
            continue #volvemos al inicio del ciclo

        saltos +=1 #sumamos a los saltoa
        tablero[fila][col] = 1 #marcamos como visitado
        pos = (fila,col) #actualizamos la posicion

    print(f"tablero final: {tablero}")
    pos = (fila,col)
    # print(pos)
    return pos,saltos
```

**main()**

Esta se encarga de ejecutar todo y retorna la posición final y el numero de saltos donde siempre será `(NxM)-1` ya que la rana solo se mueve si el mosaico no está visitado.

```py
def main():
    tablero = gen_tablero(3,4) #definimos las dimensiones del tablero
    return  recorrido(tablero)
```

**probamos**

```py
pos_final, total_saltos = main()
print(f"terminamos en la posicion: {pos_final}\nsaltos totales:{total_saltos}")
```

**Mi resultado**

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
Start game
tablero final: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
terminamos en la posicion: (-2, 2)
saltos totales:11
```

Cabe aclarar que no realicé ninguna optimización sobre el recorrido que realiza la rana, ya que esta podría (y muy probable que lo hará) evaluar un mosaico ya visitado varias veces.

Comment: si, de hecho, en el ejercicio que podia pasar que se visitara un mosaico mas de una vez, la idea final es que se rellene la matriz y cuantos pasos le tomo a la rana hacerlo por completo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda